# How to remove dots on a picture using Python and OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a project, where I have to remove the noise in the form of dots. I have tried the following code, but I'm getting an error.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('blurred_image.jpg')
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)           # get b,g,r
rgb_img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])     # switch it to rgb

# Denoising
dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img,None,10,10,7,21)

b,g,r = cv2.split(dst)           # get b,g,r
rgb_dst = cv2.merge([r,g,b])     # switch it to rgb

plt.subplot(211),plt.imshow(rgb_img)
plt.subplot(212),plt.imshow(rgb_dst)
plt.show()
```

And this is my test image

[image]

When I run the program, I'm getting a error.

```
  4 
  5 img = cv2.imread('blurred_image.jpg')
----> 6 b,g,r = cv2.split(img)           # get b,g,r
  7 rgb_img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])     # switch it to rgb
  8 

ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i run you r code and don't give me any error whats your `opencv` version ? but the noises don't been delete !!! so what you want to do in your image actually ?

Comment: @Kasra My `OpenCV` version is 2.6 .I want to minimize the noise, so that I can read the image a little better

Comment: so do you know the relationship between the colored dots in picture with its pixels ?

Comment: @Kasra No. I don't know. My guide just gave me this picture, and asked me to reduce the noise. Do I have to upgrade my `OpenCV`? I'm using Enthought Canopy as an IDE.

Comment: @Kasra And also he had given me the original image. Should I put it in my question?

Comment: it give me that too ! without ant changes! i ask you do you know the relation between colored dots with pixels of image ? in this case you must not use `cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored` function ! you must use another way ! if i will able to find it i will post it as answer !

Comment: @Kasra sure! I will try different methods too. I will update if I find a solution.